# Responsive tile layout only works in width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, tiles

I have this weird problem and I don't seem to understand where the mistake is. I am building a responsive tile layout based on a tutorial that I found on-line. In thr tutorial, tiles have 20% width and the whole site works based on that. So, when I change the percentage from 20% to 33.33%, only the width increases, the heigh remains in 20% (cuting my contents inside of the tiles). I don't understand why this is hapening... I already tried to add height to several different classes but with no result so far.

I will put the code so that you can take a look and hopefuly tell me where the mistake is...

HTML:

```
<body class="no-touch">

<div class="wrap">

  <!-- Define all of the tiles: -->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Just a caption</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/1.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">An old greenhouse</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/2.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Purple wildflowers</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/3.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">A birdfeeder</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/10.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">Crocus close-up</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxInner">
      <img src="http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/images/demo/4.jpg" />
      <div class="titleBox">The garden shop</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- /#wrap -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   // See if this is a touch device
   if ('ontouchstart' in window)
   {
      // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
      $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');

      // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
      $('div.boxInner img').click(function(){
         $(this).closest('.boxInner').toggleClass('touchFocus');
      });
   }
});
</script>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #fff;
   font: 18px 'voltaireregular',sans-serif;
   margin:auto;
}

.wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 10px;
}

.box {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   width:33.33%;
   padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.boxInner {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.boxInner img {
   width: 100%;
}

.boxInner .titleBox {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   background: #f1804b;
   opacity:0.8;
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */

.box {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {

   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */

.box {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {

   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */

   .box {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {

   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
.box {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
}
```

So... any clues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to change the padding-bottom: 20%; on the .box class to the same percentage as the width...